# COLLATION and UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation, union

I have the following queries:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENQUERY([SERVERA],
    'SELECT ''SERVERA'',[PhoneNum]
    ,[PhoneExt]
    ,COUNT(2) as CNT
    FROM [DB].[dbo].[ResourcePhone] WHERE PhoneNum like ''+44%''
    OR PhoneNum like ''+41%''
    GROUP BY PhoneNum, PhoneExt
    HAVING COUNT(2) > 1;')
        UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENQUERY([SERVERB],
    'SELECT ''SERVERA'',[PhoneNum]
    ,[PhoneExt]
    ,COUNT(2) as CNT
    FROM [DB].[dbo].[ResourcePhone] WHERE PhoneNum like ''+44%''
    OR PhoneNum like ''+41%''
    GROUP BY PhoneNum, PhoneExt
    HAVING COUNT(2) > 1;')
```

I am getting the error Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in UNION ALL operator.

I have checked the collation of the columns and database involved and they are all `Latin1_General_BIN`.  The difference is `SERVERA` has a collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and `SERVERB` has a collation of `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.  I have tried adding COLLATE `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` to the column names but this has not worked.

Can anyone advise how to resolve this?

---

Added exact query

```
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENQUERY([SERVERA],
    'SELECT ''SERVERA'',resourcephone.[PhoneNum]
    ,resourcephone.[PhoneExt]
    ,COUNT(2) as CNT
    FROM [rtc].[dbo].[ResourcePhone] WHERE PhoneNum like ''+44%''
    OR PhoneNum like ''+41%''
    GROUP BY PhoneNum, PhoneExt
    HAVING COUNT(2) > 1;')
        UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENQUERY([SERVERB],
    'SELECT ''SERVERB'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, resourcephone.[PhoneNum] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    ,resourcephone.[PhoneExt] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    ,COUNT(2) as CNT
    FROM [rtc].[dbo].[ResourcePhone] WHERE PhoneNum  like ''+44%''
    OR PhoneNum like ''+41%''
    GROUP BY PhoneNum, PhoneExt 
    HAVING COUNT(2) > 1;')
```

This query gives the following message:

Msg 457, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_BIN" in UNION ALL operator.

Comment: And what is the collation of the local server (where the query is executed)?

Comment: That is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: I think you should check the [`sp_serveroption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178532.aspx) and set the `collation compatible` option to false for both server connections.

Comment: write after `HAVING COUNT(2) > 1` this `COLLATE  Latin1_General_CI_AS` on both places

Comment: @tinka That would cause an error since you cannot add a `COLLATE` clause to a non-string expression..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem should be with the string literal (i.e. the `''SERVERA''`) as that takes on the Collation of the database where that statement is executing.

So try the following for the top part of your query:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENQUERY([SERVERA],
    'SELECT ''SERVERA'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, [PhoneNum]
...
```

And, the bottom part of the `UNION ALL` (the part for `[SERVERB]`) should probably select "SERVERB" instead of "SERVERA" as the string literal :).

And to be technical, it is taking on the Collation of the DB, not the server, though if the default connection is to `master` (or any system DB), then that would naturally be the same as the Server-level Collation since the Server-level Collation is used to create the system DBs.

**UPDATE:**

The new error you are getting after adding the `COLLATE` clause to the 2nd query in the `UNION ALL` is due to adding the `COLLATE` clause to too many of the fields. It needs to go *only* to the literal string, and *not* on the `resourcephone.[PhoneExt]` field. Doing that one extra step put the fields that were already in agreement into conflict. Since both of those table fields are in `Latin1_General_BIN`, there is no need to override the Collation on the `resourcephone.[PhoneExt]` field from either Server. It is *only* the string literal "field" that needs to be overriden, and *only* from one of the two servers: you just need to make one match the other.

Adding the `COLLATE` clause to all fields, especially ones that are already working as expected (i.e. the `resourcephone.[PhoneExt]` field) is unnecessary and is over-complicating the query.

Comment: They claimed *"I have tried adding COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS to the column names".* +1 for guessing they didn't apply this to the column with the fixed value ;)

Comment: @ypercube I did actually, and I am still getting the same error am afraid.  If I add the afore mentioned line to this and the columns I get a conflict against `Latin1_General_BIN`

Comment: Have done as requested

Comment: @Tom you added `COLLATE` only to the columns of the 2nd part of the `UNION` and not the 1st part. This agrees with the message you get ("Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_BIN"). You already said that all the columns have `Latin1_General_BIN` collation.

Comment: Ahh damn it so I did, thanks to both of you thats working now :)

Comment: @Tom where is the Latin1_General_BIN coming from?  You never mentioned that one. Probably SERVERB.

Comment: @srutzky ypercube explained that, it was me using the wrong code.

Comment: @srutzky It's in the question: *"I have checked the collation of the columns and database involved and they are all `Latin1_General_BIN`"* (also on the last error message, after the edit, last paragraph.)

Comment: @Tom I see now. I ignored that part since you said all columns had it, hence it would not be the issue and did not show up in the error message. The fix should _not_ include adding any `COLLATE` clause to the table fields. You _only_ needed to add it to the string literal. You can, and should, remove the COLLATE clause from any table fields such that you query looks exactly as I described in my answer. There is no point in overriding column collations that are not in conflict.

Comment: @ypercube Please see my update. Even though it does work, it is unnecessary to add the `COLLATE` clause to both queries. It was mistakenly added to the `resourcephone.[PhoneExt]` field when it shouldn't have been, hence fixing one error and causing the new one. The real fix is to remove the extraneous `COLLATE` rather than add yet another.

Comment: @srutzky I don't disagree with you. I wasn't sure where the `COLLATE` should be added, I thought it had to be in the first column (of each subquery) or perhaps all of them - but certainly not only in the 2nd part.

Comment: @ypercube Why do you say "but certainly not only in the 2nd part"? That shouldn't be a problem so long as you don't set at odds an already matching collation, which is what happened here when the O.P. added the `COLLATE` clause to too many fields. Collation is per field not per query. Given that the `PhoneExt` field had the same Collation in both queries, changing it in only one of them (whether 1st or 2nd) caused a second problem. Adding the `COLLATE` to only the 2nd query would work if it was the correct one, which would be the collation of the field in the 1st query, hence they would match.